# Determine calling method in AOP Advice

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I am using Spring 3.1 AOP. Is there an "easy" way to determine which class made the initial call that was intercepted by Spring AOP?

What I am trying to do is to block classes from one package from calling methods on classes in another package? The only solution I can come up with is to retrieve the Stack Trace from the current thread and traverse it to see if there is a class on the stack with the package prefix I am looking for.

Any other suggestions?